# Unpacking binary data in PHP

Tags: php, binary, pack, unpack

I'm using a third party API that allows me to upload an image via a POST request and the parameter is required to be in binary format e.g. `[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,3,...]`

I tried using the `unpack()` function and got the binary data to upload but when I try to view it on the upload server I only got a blank image BUT the image size is correct. So I think the data is there I'm just doing something wrong when unpacking.

```
        if(!$fp = fopen ($image_url, 'rb')) return 0;
        /* Read bytes from the top of the file */
        if(!$data = fread ($fp, filesize($image_path))) return 0;

        /* Unpack  data */
        $data = unpack ('C*', $data);
        //$data value: Array ( [1] => 137 [2] => 80 [3] => 78 [4] => 71 [5] => 13....
```

To test if it will convert back to the image correctly I use the `pack()` function like so:

```
        $bin = pack('C*', ...$data);
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test_image"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        echo $bin;
        exit();
```

So this will output a png file that is blank but has the same exact size as the original image. Is there are a way to fix the unpack function so that it will convert back correctly? I have no control on how to display it since it's in the third party API, so I can only correct it on the first code block.

Comment: Q: Have you examined the bytes in $data?  Is the first byte still "137" (0x89, the 1st byte in a .png file)?  Perhaps there's a different [byte ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) between your source and destination hosts?

Comment: Yep it still is! I don't think there's any difference between me and the host since if I run  both of those blocks on my end (consecutively) it still displays the blank image.

Comment: OK.  It sounds like the data might actually be OK.  In which case the *REAL* problem might not be pack/unpack at all.  Look at the HTTP traffic with Fiddler (or equivalent) and compare "successfully displayed" vs. "blank image".  Perhaps the problem is actually in one of the HTTP headers?  Or perhaps the payload isn't being sent correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tinkered a bit with what you're doing and this works for me:

```
$data = file_get_contents('test.png');
$u    = unpack('C*', $data);
$bin  = pack('C*', ...$u);

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $bin;
exit();
```

My assumption would be that your `fopen` and `fread` isn't returning what you're expecting.